# Best way to find weighted averages from two dataframes in R?

Tags: r

new to R so sorry if this is a bit broad but I'm not really even sure where to start with an approach to this problem.

I have two dataframes, df1 containing demographic data from certain Census tracts.

```
           AfricanAmerican AsianAmerican    Hispanic    White
Tract1                0.25          0.25        0.25     0.25
Tract2                0.50          0.10        0.20     0.10  
Tract3                0.05          0.10        0.35     0.50
```

And df2 contains observations polygons with the percentage of each census tract that makes up its area.

```
           Poly1      Poly2    Poly3    
Tract1      0.33       0.25     0.00     
Tract2      0.33       0.25     0.10      
Tract3      0.34       0.50     0.90
```

What I want to do is get the weighted averages of the demographic data in each observation polygon

```
          AfricanAmerican AsianAmerican    Hispanic    White
Poly1                0.26          0.15        0.27     0.29
Poly2                0.21          0.14        0.29     0.34  
Poly3                0.10          0.10        0.34     0.46
```

So far I'm thinking I could do something like

```
sum(df1$AfricanAmerican * df2$Poly1)
```

Then use a for loop to iterate over all demographic variables for one polygon, then nest that in another for loop to iterate over all polygons,  but given that I have hundreds of Census tracts and polygons in my working dataset, I was wondering if there was a better approach?

Comment: Use matrix multiplication:  `t(df2) %*% as.matrix(df1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `colSums` of the products in `mapply`.

```
t(mapply(function(...) colSums(`*`(...)), list(df1), df2))
#      AfricanAmerican AsianAmerican Hispanic  White
# [1,]          0.2645        0.1495   0.2675 0.2855
# [2,]          0.2125        0.1375   0.2875 0.3375
# [3,]          0.0950        0.1000   0.3350 0.4600
```

If you want to round to two digits, just wrap `round(..., 2)` around it.

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text='
                           AfricanAmerican AsianAmerican    Hispanic    White
     Tract1                0.25          0.25        0.25     0.25
     Tract2                0.50          0.10        0.20     0.10  
     Tract3                0.05          0.10        0.35     0.50
')
df2 <- read.table(header=T, text='
                Poly1      Poly2    Poly3    
     Tract1      0.33       0.25     0.00     
     Tract2      0.33       0.25     0.10      
     Tract3      0.34       0.50     0.90  
')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Sample Data

```
df1 <-
  tibble(
    Trat = paste0("Trat",1:3),
    AfricanAmerican = c(.25,.5,.05),
    AsianAmerican = c(.25,.1,.1),
    Hispanic = c(.25,.2,.35)
  )

df2 <-
  tibble(
    Trat = paste0("Trat",1:3),
    Poly1 = c(.33,.33,.34),
    Poly2 = c(.25,.25,.5),
    Poly3 = c(0,.1,.9)
  ) %>% 
  #Pivot df2 making a single column for all Poly values
  pivot_longer(cols = -Trat,names_to = "Poly")
```

### Code

```
df1 %>% 
  #Join df1 and df2 by Trat
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  #Grouping by Poly
  group_by(Poly) %>%
  #Sum values across variables AfricanAmerican to Hispanic
  summarise(across(AfricanAmerican:Hispanic,function(x)sum(x*value)))
```

### Output

```
Joining, by = "Trat"
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Poly  AfricanAmerican AsianAmerican Hispanic
  <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Poly1           0.264         0.150    0.268
2 Poly2           0.212         0.138    0.288
3 Poly3           0.095         0.1      0.335
```